# C++ Initialize Each Character in array of std::string of Fixed Width

Tags: c++11, initialization

Is there a way to initialize each character of each string within an array (either plain-old or `std::array`) of `std::string` using value initialization instead of `std::transform()` or looping assigning a literal or temporary object? Take for example an array of `20` `std::string` of `20` characters each where we want to initialize every character to `'x'`.

Essentially, what I would like to do is initialize every string as `std::string(WIDTH, char)`. Initializing the first is straight-forward, e.g.

```
#define NSTR  20
#define NCHR  20
...
std::string strarr[NSTR] { std::string(NCHR,'x') };
```

But there is only a single initializer provided in the initializer list for the first string and the remaining strings are initialized empty as expected due to fewer values than all being provided. Going through the value, direct, copy or list [Initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initialization) doesn't seem to provide a way through initialization. (I am trying to avoid providing either an express literal or temporary for every string in the array, e.g. if `NSTR` were `1000`, that makes it space issue, as would a `NCHR` of `1000`)

After the object is created/constructed, then either a loop and assigning a temporary (or literal) or [std::transform](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) (or [std::fill](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/fill)) provide a simple way, e.g.

```
    std::string strarr[NSTR] {};
    
    for (auto& s : strarr) {
        s = std::string(NCHR,'x');
    }
```

or

```
    std::transform (strarr, strarr + NSTR, strarr, 
                    [](std::string s) { return s = std::string(NCHR,'x'); } );
```

or the shortest, using [std::fill_n](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/fill_n) and a temporary string object:

```
    std::fill_n (strarr, NSTR, std::string (NCHR,'x'));
```

Using a container for the `std::string` doesn't seem to expose any additional single-shot initialization that would also initialize all strings, e.g.

```
    std::array<std::string,NSTR> strarr{};
```

Is there some direct way to initialize each char in an array of `std::string`, or is setting them after the array is defined the way to go? If so (or not), why?

(I suspect it is the latter due to `strarr` not being a completed instance at the time the initializer is evaluated precluding the use of an iterator of that instance. However, after a read of latest draft of [[dcl.dcl]](http://eel.is/c++draft/#dcl.dcl) for the C++20 standard, I can't find the section that says you *can't* or one that says you *can* -- or I"m just not familiar enough with the vernacular to identify the relevant section...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an immediately invoked initializing lambda:

```cpp
#include <array>
#include <string>

constexpr std::size_t NSTR{20u};
constexpr std::size_t NCHR{20u};

int main() {


    const auto strarr = []() {
        std::array<std::string, NSTR> strings{};
        for(auto& s : strings) {
            s = std::string(NCHR, 'x');
        }
        return strings;
    }(); //Immediately Invoked Initializing Lambda

    return 0;
}
```

IIIL's are generally used for initialization of variables that would otherwise be a complex process. This also makes it so the variable can now be declared `const` when before it could not due to post-declaration initializations via loops (`const` all the things!).

Comment: Okay, now we are getting somewhere. This must have been something that gcc added between versions 7.4.1 and 10.2.0. In 7.4.1, I get `error: ‘__closure’ is not a constant expression`, but on the current version it compiles without issue, even with `-std=c++14`. I'll have to go delve back into the standard and find out what allows doing this with a lambda.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin It's a typo on my part. The NSTR and NCHR cannot be part of the closures. Declaring them as globals fixes it.

Comment: Yep, that was it, now it compiles fine on both 7.4.1 and 10.2.0. So gcc made some change to the closure semantics between the versions, but the IIIL is the same. Hah!!!, you can even use `std::fill_n (strings, NSTR, std::string (NCHR,'x'));` instead of the loop. So it is the lamba itself that allows the complex initializaiton. One of these days I'll learn C++ to the same level I understand C.... (some day..)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin It was a language change, not specific to gcc. I got a similar error in VS2019: `error C2975: '_Size': invalid template argument for 'std::array', expected compile-time constant expression`. which told me that by using closures, the compile-time constant specifier was no longer true and they were being copied.

Comment: I knew there should be a way to do it, and I have this lingering suspicion I've seen it before, but did not know what to call it. Time well spent re-reading the declarations and initialization part of the standard, but I should have just searched `"c++ initialize complex data structure lambda"` and IIFE, IILE (or IIIL) pops right up. (of course the `lambda` part of the search is important) Now just to track back and find out what section of the standard provides for it. Thanks for your help.